# How can I fix terminator? It doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, python, terminator

When I run `terminator` in terminal, it doesn't work. The error is this:

```
$ terminator

  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 119
    except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:

                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Error in sys.excepthook:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook

    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in 
<module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>

    import apt

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

    import apt_pkg

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'


Original exception was:

  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 119

    except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
                                ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix it? I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? Also, what is the first line of `/usr/bin/terminator`? Is it something like `#!/usr/bin/python3`? or is it `#!/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: It is #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Do you have python2 installed? Run `sudo apt install python` or what is the output of `which python`?

Comment: [This solution worked for me. Thank you.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122644/1026695)

Answer (score 12):

I fixed it by editing `/usr/bin/terminator` and changing the python version. First, open the file with:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/terminator
```

Then, change the first line from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

To this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

Finally, save the file and you're ready to go!

Comment: This solution temporally fixed the issue but I guess the update of `terminator` will break it again.

Answer (score 3):

Terminator require python2 libraries but from your output it seems it is using python3 to run. Also, according to [release notes of Ubuntu 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Other_base_system_changes_since_16.04_LTS),

> Python 2 is no longer installed by default. Python 3 has been updated to 3.6. This is the last LTS release to include Python 2 in main.

To install Python2 in 18.04, run:

```
sudo apt install python-minimal
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to reinstall packages with `apt_pkg` with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-apt python3-apt
```

and to be completely sure reinstall Terminator with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall terminator
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. It had same problem